# Is There A Better Way To Organize My Plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, plist

I am making an iPhone app.

Table view has 3 views:(1) muscles -> (2) exercises (for that muscle) -> (3) exercise's detail

Here is the plist I currently have, its organized how it is because I followed a tutorial on how to make it work with tables and that is the format they used.

Here are a couple pictures of my .plist.  I have two pics so you can see the name tag for the muscle is still in the same list (just after the child items).

http://www.box.net/shared/static/4i3yyjg0iq.png

http://www.box.net/shared/static/b1kkep55vd.png

Thanks!

Edit:

Here is the plist from text edit. (sorry for some reason I can't get the spacing right in for the post).

```
<array> <dict>
    <key>ItemChild</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Ab Roller</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Ab Crunch Machine</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>Advanced Kettlebell Windmill</string>
        </dict>
         </array>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Abdominals</string>
</dict>


</array>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Abdominals</string>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .plist is just a copy on disk of information that you need to have in memory when your program is running. If you can get the info, and your code works, then worrying about the formatting of the .plist file doesn't make much sense to me. Whatever works, works, in this case.

**Update:** Okay, I think that you can indeed make this both more concise and more meaningful. Here are my thoughts.

The base container of the info is an array. Each item in the array is a dictionary. The key/object pairs in the dictionary are the muscle's name, and an array of the exercises. Each item in the exercises array is another dictionary, whose key/object pairs are the name of the exercise, and whatever you decide to use for the detail. The end result will look like this:

```
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>muscleName</key>
    <string>Abdominals</string>
    <key>exercises</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>exerciseName</key>
        <string>Ab Roller</string>
        <key>exerciseDetail</key>
        <string></string> <!-- or possibly data -->
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>exerciseName</key>
        <string>Ab Crunch Machine</string>
        <key>exerciseDetail</key>
        <string></string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>exerciseName</key>
        <string>Advanced Kettlebell Windmill</string>
        <key>exerciseDetail</key>
        <string></string>
      </dict>
      <!-- more exercises? -->
    </array>
    <!-- End Abdominals -->
  </dict>
  <dict>
    <key>muscleName</key>
    <string>AnotherMuscle</string>
    <key>exercises</key>
    <array>
      <!-- dicts of the exercises for this muscle -->
    </array>
    <!-- End AnotherMuscle -->
  </dict>
  <!-- more muscles -->
</array>
```

I think this will make your .plist creation easier, and make your coding easier and more readable, when you get to that stage.

If you have a huge amount of information (and it sounds like you do), you might also consider splitting it up into three (or more) files: Muscle Names, Exercises, Exercise Details.

Comment: Thanks Josh! I'm updating my original post with the plist details.

Comment: And the reason why I would rather have it done simpler is because I still need to fill in 100x the data already there and the way it is formatted right now is taking me a long time to fill in the data.

Comment: Editing this stuff by hand is a pain, for sure. The spacing in your post looks just fine. One more question: you mentioned "Exercise Detail"; is that information graphical, or just not included in the .plist, or what?

Comment: Thanks josh. Right now that stuff is not in my plist at all but it will probaly end up being some strings and maybe an image or something.

Comment: Thanks Josh that definately look better! It took me a while to figure out how to load the current plist into their respective tables so I hope doing the same for the new plist won't be as difficult.

Comment: One last thing, when I used your format and then opened the file in xcode, it doesn't show any root array, it just has a list of dictionary items.  Is this ok?  Here is a pic to show you: http://www.box.net/shared/static/6i76h8qa0x.png

Comment: That's exactly what it should look like, yes. The array is just displayed as the list of all the items it contains.

Comment: Josh, if you don't mind, could you help me set up with pushing the data to the tables.  I'm having a little trouble implementing the new plist. I'll make another question in a minute.  Thanks.